# django template how to display in datatable

Tags: django, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display templates value in datatable (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229191/display-templates-value-in-datatable-django)

my model.py file ...

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uhid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

---

here is my view.py file 
now what im doin is something like dis...

```
def patient(request):
    patient = PatientInfo()
    patient.name = request.POST["name"]
    patient.uhid = request.POST["uhid"]
    patient.age = request.POST["age"]
    patient.gender = request.POST["gender"]

    t = Template(" my name is {{ patient }}")
    c = Context({ "patient": patient })
    d = t.render(c)  // im using this dnt knw its a right approach or not..
 return HttpResponse(d)
```

---

now my html file  where i want to display my form fields name ,age,..gender.
i dnt knw how to display what m doin here is the code...as follows.

```
{% for patients in patient %}-->

            <tr><td>{{patients.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{patients.uhid }}</td>
            <td>{{patients.age }}</td>
            <td>{{patients.gender }}</td>
```

now my question is how to display name ,age, gender ... in my datatable.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As i understtod,
your model and view is:

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
uhid = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
age = models.IntegerField()
gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py:

```
def patient(request): 
 patients = PatientInfo.objects.all()
 template = "path_to_template/mytemplate.html"
 data = {
    'patients': patients ,
    }

return render_to_response( template, data, 
                           context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

in your mytemplate.html:

```
    {% for patient in patients %}
       <tr>
         <td>{{patients.name }}</td>
         <td>{{patients.uhid }}</td>
         <td>{{patients.age }}</td>
         <td>{{patients.gender }}</td>
        </tr>
    {%endfor%}
```

This will work in your case

Comment: yes i want to display the data which is already saved in database.

Comment: don't worry...is this code works?