# django template value display

Tags: django, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display templates value in datatable (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229191/display-templates-value-in-datatable-django)

actually I'm new to django as ur modified code....
as follows: but there is one problem which im facing when ever im trying to save new entryies its shows error by Exception Value:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'
and path_to_template dis is m not getting exactly a bit confusion in dat...

actually in my setting.py file  i did something like dis:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/templates/',
)
```

---

your modified code:

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
uhid = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
age = models.IntegerField()
gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py:

```
def patient(request): 
 patients = PatientInfo.objects.all()

 t = Template("path_to_template/mytemplate.html") 
 c = Context({ "patients": patients }) 
 d =     t.render(c) 
 return HttpResponse(d)
```

in your mytemplate.html:

{% for patient in patients %}
   
     {{patients.name }}
     {{patients.uhid }}
     {{patients.age }}
     {{patients.gender }}
    
{%endfor%}

Comment: STOP. You aren't helping yourself by creating all these duplicates; they will only come back to bite you on the derriere in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for patient in patients %}
<tr>
 <td>{{patient_s_.name }}</td>
 <td>{{patient_s_.uhid }}</td>
 <td>{{patient_s_.age }}</td>
 <td>{{patient_s_.gender }}</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

First of all you should remove the S at the end.
You are calling .name .uhid etc within a queryset instance, not in a "Patient" class.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: again this error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'plz help me... not getting exactly.

Comment: i want to display my database saved data as well as want user should input field and den save data and that data should b displayed in  datatables.